# removing backslashes in the query using codeigniter mysql

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

Post value is multi select, means   values are coming in the form of array

```
if(!empty($_POST['form_type']))
            {
               $test = implode("','",$_POST['form_type']);
               $this->db->where_in('enquiry.type_of_enquiry',"'".$test."'");
            }
```

my query is like this

```
SELECT `sobha_enquiry`.`name`, `sobha_enquiry`.`date_created`, `sobha_enquiry`.`company`, `sobha_enquiry`.`form_of`, `sobha_enquiry`.`projectname`, `sobha_enquiry`.`city`, `sobha_enquiry`.`country`, `sobha_enquiry`.`phone`, `sobha_enquiry`.`type_of_enquiry`, `sobha_enquiryzone`.`enquiry_id`, `sobha_enquiry`.`hearaboutus`, `sobha_enquiry`.`email`, `sobha_enquiry`.`comments`, `sobha_enquiry`.`address`, `sobha_admin`.`id`, `sobha_admin`.`city_id` FROM (`sobha_senquiry`) LEFT JOIN `sobha_enquiryzone` ON `sobha_enquiryzone`.`enquiry_id` =`sobha_enquiry`.`id` LEFT JOIN `sobha_admin` ON `sobha_admin`.`city_id`=`sobha_enquiryzone`.`city_id` WHERE `sobha_enquiry`.`type_of_enquiry` IN ('\'register form\',\'feedback form\'') GROUP BY `sobha_enquiry`.`id` ORDER BY `sobha_enquiry`.`id` desc LIMIT 15
```

since i used implode function it is coming like this IN ('\'register form\',\'feedback form\'') i want to remove those backslashes . Please help me

Comment: looking for stripslashes? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: k let me see that link

Comment: i have added new code like this $test = implode("','",$_POST['form_type']);
      $test1=stripslashes($test); it is not working

Comment: Have you thought to do echo $test; so you can see what is happening?

Comment: `where_in` accepts an array of values as well, so you can push in the values you want to check against?

Comment: thank you every one for helping i found the solution like this $this->db->where("sobha_enquiry.type_of_enquiry IN('".$test."') " );

Answer (score 2):

`$this->db->where_in()` will accept array as second argument.

So there is no need for imploding the data.

```
if(!empty($_POST['form_type']))
{
    $this->db->where_in('enquiry.type_of_enquiry',$_POST['form_type']);
}
```

This will result as,

```
 WHERE `enquiry`.`type_of_enquiry` IN ('register form','feedback form')
```

You can refer this link for more info, [Codeigniter Active Record Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)